# CloudFront custom file location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So this is my first time with AWS and server setup stuff. I have an S3 configured as well as CloudFront on AWS. Since the origin of my CloudFront is set to my S3, the files on S3 I believe will be retrieved say as follows via CloudFront

S3 - https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket/uploads/logo/UfB7wDrn9A5r.jpg

CloudFront - https://randomstring.cloudfront.net/uploads/logo/UfB7wDrn9A5r.jpg

However what I would like to achieve - may seem a long shot - is my CloudFront path for my image to be something like -

https://randomstring.cloudfront.net/UfB7wDrn9A5r.jpg

So basically irrespective of what the path of the file is in S3, I would want the file to be present only at the root in CloudFront. Is this even remotely possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> irrespective of what the path of the file is in S3

Irrespective, no.  This isn't something you can do out of the box with S3 and/or CloudFront.

It is possible to collapse a *single* path in the bucket, such that the content of /uploads/logo would appear in the root of the CloudFront distribution, but all files not in /uploads/logo would be inaccessible through CloudFront.

This is done by setting the [Origin Path](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath) in CloudFront.

If you used /uploads as the origin path, then the files in /uploads/logo/* would appear as just /logo/* in CloudFront, but it doesn't sound like that is your intended outcome.

Anything else would require an intermediate system between CloudFront and S3 to "hunt" for the desired resource, which would be inefficient and time-consuming, not to mention the possibility of filename collisions.

Comment: How can we achieve to see how cloud front has the files?
Im trying to make invalidations for a single file but it doesnt work. The documentations its quite blur with this

Comment: @carrasc0 it isn't possible to see what CloudFront has, but the path should be the same as the request path.  If you have CloudFront caching based on query string parameters, you also need to put `*` at the end of the invalidation request path, e.g. `/assets/images/cat.png*`.  Remember that invalidation request paths are case-sensitive.

Comment: The situation is that i have URL's this type:

https://xxxxx-xxxxx.cloudfront.net/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJwZXRtZS11c2VycyIsImtleSI6InVzZXItNjNiODEzNDcxNGJkNzFjNmE2NWJhOTc4LTIwMjMtMDEtMDYtMTQtNTItMDMtMjY2NjAtYXQiOiJqcGVnIn19

Since Im using a serverless solution template.

I tried to use the original path in the bucket -no working. This path, no working either. Only that works is the delete all path "/*" but i dont want to delete all cache just because one user changed its profile photo.

Any thoughts on this? 3 days stuck on this

Comment: @carrasc0 the hostname doesn't matter, and isn't used for invalidation requests.  The path that the browser *requests* is what you need to put in for invalidation.  If the browser requests `https://dzczcexample.cloudfront.net/pics/profiles/user123.png` then you want to invalidate `/pics/profiles/user123.png*`.